# How can I web scrape products from a product catalog page using Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, kaggle

Please note I'm a newbie when it comes to web scraping. I have managed to successfully scrape products from another catalog but not having much luck this time.

I'm using Python's beautifulsoup module to web scrape products from the page https://drop.com/all-communities/drops. However, cannot grab the product cards. My issue is with the fact that there are a lot of nested classes and within each tag there are multiple classes listed. I have tried playing around with the class attributes but nothing seemed to work.

The HTML is too lengthy so I won't include it here but please take a look at it.

This is the code I have:

```py
def scrapesinglepage(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    allproduct = soup.find_all("div", class_ = ['GridgridItemInner1hwGE', 'Link2link1aAsF', 'GridgridItemInner1hwGE'])

for item in all_product:
    product_name = item.find("div", class_ = ['Text__text__PazWx', 'Text__type--headline__2tK0P', 'Text__line_clamp--2__2UPZw']).get_text()
    print(product_name) # prints 'Audiophile' instead of product name
    scrapesinglepage("https://drop.com/all-communities/drops")
```

I have tried other variations of the `find_all` method including

```py
['Grid___c--1__2obI2', 'wdio_card', 'shop_card', 'Card__card__1RLRm', 'Card__background--light-gray__F8hUw', 'Grid__gridItem__2qOsq']
['Grid___c--1__2obI2',  'wdio_card', 'shop_card', 'wdio_drop_card', 'wdio_drop_card--live', 'Card__card__1RLRm', 'Card__background--light-gray__F8hUw', 'Grid__gridItem__2qOsq']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @Mr PizzaGuy thank you for the edits :)

Comment: That page is dynamically loaded using jscript, so requests can't handle it. You'll need something like selenium or requests-html.

Comment: No problem @bronsco_0, just doing my job.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting ohhh ok that makes sense. I found a great article on scraping dynamic sites so will read up on that.

Comment: You actually don't need to use selenium or requests-html (although you still could use though, they'd work). But the other option here is to just access the data through the api/XHR.

Comment: @chitown88 that's perfect, thank you!

Comment: @chitown88 so I tried scraping using the XHR, BUT it's unfortunately not as easy as I hoped. They pay a service to index their web pages which costs them per search. Obviously web scrapers would be costing them a lot of money if they allowed this so they have prevented this.

Comment: I've tried selenium as well, but since the site requires you to log in first in order to view the catalogue and I'm not able to get auto sign in working, I'm going to have to just scrape the products manually through the JSON.

Comment: My workaround is to save the raw JSON generated via the query requests found under the Network tab. This is going to be a bit laborious since there are 20,054 products in total and the page only loads 35 results at a time, which means I'm going to end up with 570 JSON files, but if I can find a way to automate this then it will be much more efficient.